# Sort date property in object in ascending order Angularjs/Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I console.log the `details` variable, I get the following results:

`details:{
          1:{
             2015-2-10 : 0
             2015-2-11 : 0
             2015-2-12 : 0
             2015-2-13 : 0
             2015-2-14 : 0
             2015-2-15 : 0
             2015-2-16 : 0
             2015-2-17 : 0
             2015-2-18 : 0
             2015-2-19 : 0
             2015-2-2  : 0
             2015-2-20 : 0
             2015-2-21 : 0
             2015-2-22 : 0
             2015-2-23 : 0
             2015-2-24 : 0
             2015-2-25 : 0 
             2015-2-26 : 0
             2015-2-27 : 1
             2015-2-28 : 1
             2015-2-3  : 0
             2015-2-4  : 0
             2015-2-5  : 0
             2015-2-6  : 0
             2015-2-7  : 0
             2015-2-8  : 0
             2015-2-9  : 0
             2015-3-1  : 0
          }
 }`

I want to do is to display the dates with ascending order. So the output will become:

`details:{
          1:{
             2015-2-2  : 0
             2015-2-3  : 0
             2015-2-4  : 0
             2015-2-5  : 0
             2015-2-6  : 0
             2015-2-7  : 0
             2015-2-8  : 0
             2015-2-9  : 0
             2015-2-10 : 0
             2015-2-11 : 0
             2015-2-12 : 0
             2015-2-13 : 0
             2015-2-14 : 0
             2015-2-15 : 0
             2015-2-16 : 0
             2015-2-17 : 0
             2015-2-18 : 0
             2015-2-19 : 0
             2015-2-20 : 0
             2015-2-21 : 0
             2015-2-22 : 0
             2015-2-23 : 0
             2015-2-24 : 0
             2015-2-25 : 0 
             2015-2-26 : 0
             2015-2-27 : 1
             2015-2-28 : 1
             2015-3-1  : 0
          }
 }`

My question: Is it possible to do it?

my plunker is http://plnkr.co/edit/dQO3D1Omc0o7ZH9TfeUZ?p=preview
Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort JavaScript object by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Answer (score 1):

> My question: Is it possible to do it?

**As of ES2015**, yes, it's possible, but it's almost always a bad idea. When you want a specific order, use an array or (in some limited situations) a `Map` (`Map` objects are ordered strictly by when an entry for a key was first added).

The reason it's possible with your specific example is that those properties are all "own" properties (not inherited) and their names are not [integer indexes](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#integer-index). For that subset of properties, the order is the order the property was adding to the object. So to do what you describe, you'd create a new object, and add the properties to it in the order you want them to appear.

But again: Don't do that. :-) Use an array of `name`/`value` objects, or a `Map`.

---

**As of ES5** (when this question was first asked): No. The structure you've quoted is an object with property names like `"2015-02-28"`. Objects in JavaScript *have no order to their properties at all*. To have order, you must (for now) have an array. ES6 will introduce `Map` objects, which are maps ordered by the *insertion order* of their keys. But ES5 doesn't have those.

That doesn't mean you can't *access* those properties in any order you want. You can get an array of the property names via `Object.keys`, and you can sort arrays however you like.